# How do I fix create lambda error during "ask deploy"

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I did the following "ask deploy":

> RI-mac:multiple-streams egilchri$ ask deploy
>
> -------------------- Create Skill Project --------------------
>
> Profile for the deployment: [default]
>
> Skill Id: amzn1.ask.skill.cdb74c79-59a5-4e01-adb2-cad787040dd9
>
> Skill deployment finished.
>
> Model deployment finished.
>
> Create Lambda error.
>
> InvalidParameterValueException: The runtime parameter of nodejs6.10 is
>   no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We
>   recommend you use the new runtime (nodejs10.x) while creating or
>   updating functions.

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I haven't used this in a while. Updgrading ask cli seemed to do the trick.

On MacOS

```
sudo npm install -g ask-cli
```